# How to shortcut query building with EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have model that holds user input and i have database query construction using this data with EF. All params are optional.

My question: can query building be done in a shorter way?

Model with user input:

```
public class PostFilterModel
{
    public PostFilterModel()
    {
        Currency = Enumerable.Empty<Currency>();
        Condition = Enumerable.Empty<Condition>();
        Transmission = Enumerable.Empty<Transmission>();
        Rudder = Enumerable.Empty<Rudder>();
        Body = Enumerable.Empty<Body>();
        Engine = Enumerable.Empty<Engine>();
        Gear = Enumerable.Empty<Gear>();
    }

public int City { get; set; }
public int Region { get; set; }
public int Brand { get; set; }
public int Model { get; set; }
public int MinHorsePower { get; set; }
public int MaxHorsePower { get; set; }
public int MinEngineCapacity { get; set; }
public int MaxEngineCapacity { get; set; }
public int MinMileage { get; set; }
public int MaxMileage { get; set; }
public int MinPrice { get; set; }
public int MaxPrice { get; set; }
public int MinYear { get; set; }
public int MaxYear { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<Currency> Currency { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Condition> Condition { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Transmission> Transmission { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Rudder> Rudder { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Body> Body { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Engine> Engine { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Gear> Gear { get; set; }
}
```

And my query builder based on model:

```
public ICollection<Post> GetByFilter(PostFilterModel filter)
        {
            IQueryable<Post> Posts = uow.PostRepository.GetAll();

            if (filter.City > 0)
                Posts = Posts.Where(p => p.City.CityId == filter.City);

            if (filter.Region > 0)
                Posts = Posts.Where(p => p.City.Region.RegionId == filter.Region);

            if (filter.Brand > 0)
                Posts = Posts.Where(p => p.Car.Brand.BrandId == filter.Brand);

            if (filter.Model > 0)
                Posts = Posts.Where(p => p.Car.Model.ModelId == filter.Model);

            if (filter.MinPrice > 0)
                Posts = Posts.Where(p => p.Price >= filter.MinPrice);

            if (filter.MaxPrice > 0)
                Posts = Posts.Where(p => p.Price <= filter.MaxPrice);

            if (filter.MinYear > 0)
                Posts = Posts.Where(p => p.Car.Year >= filter.MinYear);

            if (filter.MaxYear > 0)
                Posts = Posts.Where(p => p.Car.Year <= filter.MaxYear);

            if (filter.Condition.Count() > 0)
                Posts = Posts.Where(p => filter.Condition.Contains(p.Car.Condition));

            if (filter.Transmission.Count() > 0)
                Posts = Posts.Where(p => filter.Transmission.Contains(p.Car.Transmission));

            if (filter.Rudder.Count() > 0)
                Posts = Posts.Where(p => filter.Rudder.Contains(p.Car.Rudder));

            if (filter.Body.Count() > 0)
                Posts = Posts.Where(p => filter.Body.Contains(p.Car.Body));

            if (filter.Engine.Count() > 0)
                Posts = Posts.Where(p => filter.Engine.Contains(p.Car.Engine));

            if (filter.Gear.Count() > 0)
                Posts = Posts.Where(p => filter.Gear.Contains(p.Car.Gear));

            return Posts.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by shorter? Less code? More automated?

Comment: Use Expression Trees http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are wanting to use less code, I'd prefer readability over less code. The only things I can think to do without breaking readability too much are things like combining all your logic into a single Where clause, something like:

```
    public ICollection<Post> GetByFilter(PostFilterModel filter)
    {
        return uow.PostRepository.GetAll().Where(p => 
            (filter.City <= 0 || p.City.CityId == filter.City) &&
            (filter.Region <= 0 || p.Region.RegionId == filter.Region) &&
            (filter.Brand <= 0 || p.Car.Brand.BrandId == filter.Brand) &&
            (filter.Model <= 0 || p.Car.Model.ModelId == filter.Model) &&
            (filter.MinPrice <= 0 || p.Price >= filter.MinPrice) &&
            (filter.MaxPrice <= 0 || p.Price <= filter.MaxPrice) &&
            (filter.MinYear <= 0 || p.Car.Year >= filter.MinYear) &&
            (filter.MaxYear <= 0 || p.Car.Year <= filter.MaxYear) &&
            (filter.Condition.Count() <= 0 || filter.Condition.Contains(p.Car.Condition)) &&
            (filter.Transmission.Count() <= 0 || filter.Transmission.Contains(p.Car.Transmission)) &&
            (filter.Rudder.Count() <= 0 || filter.Rudder.Contains(p.Car.Rudder)) &&
            (filter.Body.Count() <= 0 || filter.Body.Contains(p.Car.Body)) &&
            (filter.Engine.Count() <= 0 || filter.Engine.Contains(p.Car.Engine)) &&
            (filter.Gear.Count() <= 0 || filter.Gear.Contains(p.Car.Gear)) &&
             );
    }
```

But you aren't really saving much.

You could use dynamic generation of the query by storing the clauses on the filter, but this is just moving code elsewhere and is building dependencies into your code.

I implore you not to use single line if statements (ie without the braces) as this is a bug waiting to happen.

My view, keep the code readable rather than short.